# Two projects angular but one project working another not working

Tags: angular

**here i am create user,artists under the projects folder and i am run server ng serve user projects works but i want to run same port like (localhost:40001) run user and artists (localhost:40001/artists)projects its possible or not in angular**
**angular json**

**user**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>User</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**artists**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Artists</title>
  <base href="/artists">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

**my-lib**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-my-lib',
  template: `
    <p>
      my-lib works!
    </p>
  `,
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class MyLibComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "user": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/user",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/user/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/user",
            "index": "projects/user/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/user/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/user/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/user/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/user/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/user/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/user/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/user/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/user/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "user:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "user:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "user:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/user/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/user/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/user/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/user/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/user/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/user/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/user/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "artists": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/artists",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/artists/src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/artists",
            "index": "projects/artists/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/artists/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/artists/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/artists/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "projects/artists/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/artists/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/artists/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "baseHref": "/artists",
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/artists/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/artists/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "artists:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "artists:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "artists:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/artists/src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/artists/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/artists/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/artists/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "projects/artists/src/favicon.ico",
              "projects/artists/src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "projects/artists/src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "my-lib": {
      "projectType": "library",
      "root": "projects/my-lib",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/my-lib/src",
      "prefix": "lib",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:ng-packagr",
          "options": {
            "project": "projects/my-lib/ng-package.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.prod.json"
            },
            "development": {
              "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.lib.json"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "projects/my-lib/src/test.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/my-lib/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "projects/my-lib/karma.conf.js"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "user"
}
```

**how to if /artist to only artist index file open else / to user index file only open**

Comment: You cannot run 2 servers on the same port. If you want to do this, you can run 2 servers on different ports + add an additional server (for example on `8080`) that will redirect `/artist` to `3000` and `/user` to `3001`. Then you access the application via 8080

Comment: Usually in Angular you have one application, one index.html, you then define a module with two routes '' and 'artists'. For the empty route '', you display users component and for 'artists' route you display artists component. Check https://angular.io/guide/router-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run 2 servers on the same port. The best you can do is :

- Start the "Artist" server on **4001**
- Start the "User" server on **4002**
- Create a proxy on **8000** that will redirect `/artist` to **4001** and `/user` to **4002**

The proxy can be created with whatever you want. The real server will probably be a Apache/Nginx etc.

In development, you can create one easily with [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) and [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy). Here is the recipe :

- Create a folder for your proxy project and go in there : `mkdir my-proxy && cd my-proxy`
- Initialize a npm project with all default values : `npm init -y`
- Install needed dependencies : `npm i --save express http-proxy`

Create a `proxy.js` file with the following content :

```js
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
var apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();
var serverArtist = 'http://localhost:4001',
    serverUser = 'http://localhost:4002';

app.all("/artist/*", function(req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverArtist });
});

app.all("/user/*", function(req, res) {
  apiProxy.web(req, res, {target: serverUser});
});

app.listen(8000);
```

Then, start your server with `node proxy.js`

Access the app via port 8000 like : `localhost:8000/artist`

Comment: its working but show blank page.    js and css not loading how to solve